# How can I cut and paste HTML to Microsoft Word and get a Style?

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I am copying some simple HTML from a my web browser (Chrome) into a Microsoft Word.

Basic example HTML such as this:

```
<h5>Example Title</h5>
<p>Some example body text</p>
<p class="Example Style">Some example body text</p>
```

MS Word is capable of picking up and automatically converting heading tags. However, when the para HTML tag is converted to MS Word, it comes out as an odd style, not the "Normal" style from the MS Word doc, and not the style that was in the HTML.

I am looking to cut and paste HTML into MS Word and get a desired MS Word style result, such as "Normal" or "Example Style"

Comment: This question is about _using_ MS Word, not about _programming_, and doesn't belong on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @StephenP - I am asking _how_ to write HTML code that can be cut and paste into MS Word.  I am seeking a code solution.

Comment: Do you have a more realistic (but still small) example?  If you're _actually_ putting those `<pre>` tags around your content I would _expect_ it to come out "odd".

Comment: @StephenP - I am sorry ... it's my first SO question.  I mis-used the format for code block, I thought the pre tags were needed.  I have now fixed the example.

Answer (score -1):

Look for a setting for plain text

[Change MS Word's default paste setting to plain text](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/change-ms-words-default-paste-setting-to-plain-text/)

Comment: Link is broken.  Extra %20 and a missing :.

This would help with the Normal style, I think.  Will test.  Any idea for getting other style like "Example Text"?

Comment: Here is the [corrected link](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/change-ms-words-default-paste-setting-to-plain-text/).

Unfortunately, this solution drops the header tags, so you end up with all Normal text.